# Using Facebook open graph how would I post on friend's feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am creating an app which tries to write on either my time line or on my friends feed.

My object is say "**Article**"

And action is say "**request**"

I am trying to do 2 things-

1. Write on own timeline saying "Has **Requested** an **Article**" - This is working fine
2. Write on my friend's feed saying "**Pratik** has **Requested** an **Article**" - I am not sure how to do this.

Help please.

Comment: Why do you need that, overall it will read like- Pratik Pratik has requested an article, doesn't makes sense, right?

Comment: No basically I wanted to appear on friend's feed some think like "Pratik has Requested an Article"

Comment: That would not be a normal post, but publishing an action. And that you can only do for the active user.

Comment: @CBroe Which means that what I am trying to achieve is not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that you cannot write on a friend's wall, the second option is not possible.

You can use mention tagging https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/tagging/#mentions to include a friend's name in an action.

Comment: Tagging is something which I am currently doing. Wanted a more cleaner way. Thanks BTW